# Как делается наложение одежды 2d персонажа в unity

Tags: unity3d

Как делается наложение одежды 2d персонажа в unity? Есть персонаж, на него хочу сделать одежду. Когда одежды мало, можно просто перерисовать анимацию, но когда, например, 3 вида одежды и в каждом 5 вариантов - это огромное количество комбинаций, как поступить в таком случае?

Comment: Возможно не в тему, но можно попробовать поиграть с Pivot у спрайтов, т.е. взять персонажа зафиксировать точки, где у него крепиться одежда. А спрайт с одеждой сдвигать pivot, этот pivot должен совпадать с точкой на персонаже. Допустим взять кепку и цилиндр, размер у них разный, pivot собственно тоже разный выставлять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вопрос слишком обширен, и я думаю, что вам не мешало бы добавить информации о том, как у вас устроено всё в проекте по этой сфере.

Вариантов реализации может быть уйма: от простого наложения спрайта поверх спрайта персонажа (то есть по оси z одежду сделать ближе к камере) до заморочки в виде создания готовых спрайтов с руками, ногами, головой и т.д. под определённый головной убор.

Если у вас персонаж - это набор спрайт листов, то никак. Вы просто не сможете отловить положение конечностей в тот или иной момент. Ну, сможете, конечно, но это будет очень сложная, ресурсозатратная, а в итоге практически ничего не делающая система, что будет делать её глупой.